# ios7 not working with cordova3 properly

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, cordova-3

I am using cordova3.3 with ios 7. I am facing the following problems and would like to know more about them.

the native parts and api we have used:

```
1-alert;
2-appinbrowser for app help;inapp browser close button not visible
3-loader;
4-connection(checking user internet connectivity)
```

All the above functions have a problem with ios 7. Some other problems with Ios (design issues):

```
1-the keyboard breaks the design and it looks little awkward for some time till we finish typing.
2-the fonts are little small.
```

The most disabling problem is that I am unable to debug the program properly, actually there is a console available but that is not working with ios 7 right now.

```
heuristic solutions and their effects-

1-used the normal alert but it gives a weird alert like index.html and alert message.
```

Are these issues solved or do they still persist in ios 7?

Comment: thanks for the edit mathias

Comment: I would recommend searching at http://phonegap.com/support/ or the issue tracker at http://cordova.apache.org.